# React Native Async Promise Pending Forever

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am using Firebase Firestore, I am using three awaits. The logic behind this is that the output should not return if there is nothing in the firestore collection, so the output should only be set by one function. I am wondering if the three awaits are causing it to pend eternally or if there is something I fail to understand about async/await. I am new to this, so any resources or answers help. Thank you!

```
componentDidMount() {

        // sends to different home screen based on authentication
        async function authSwitch(cred) {

            var output;

            await firebase.firestore().collection('Students').where("uid", "==", cred).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    output = "student";
                });
            });

            await firebase.firestore().collection('Admin').where("uid", "==", cred).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    console.log(doc.id);
                    output = "admin";
                });
            });

            await firebase.firestore().collection('Preceptors').where("uid", "==", cred).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    output = "preceptor";
                });
            });

            return output;
        }

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user) {
                console.log(user.uid);
                console.log(authSwitch(user.uid));
                this.props.navigation.navigate(authSwitch(user.uid));

            }
            else {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator size = "large"></ActivityIndicator>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `then()` that doesn't return anything. As far as I know this means that you're consuming the promise, that `await` is expecting.

As far as I can see, the correct way to write these queries and promises is:

```
async function authSwitch(cred) {

    var output;

    let querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Students').where("uid", "==", cred).get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        output = "student";
    });

    querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Admin').where("uid", "==", cred).get()
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id);
        output = "admin";
    });

    querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Preceptors').where("uid", "==", cred).get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        output = "preceptor";
    });

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, however that returns the same result in the console. A promise is returned, but after the promise another function has a console.log in it that never ends up printing.

Comment: can you show us that other function, in case the issue is in there?

Comment: Yes, I edited the original post to show the other function.

Comment: You're missing an `await` in there: `console.log(await authSwitch(user.uid));`

Comment: That is outside the function

Comment: Yes, but the `authSwitch` function itself is asynchronous, so it returns a promise. When you call the function, you will either need to handle that promise (with a `then()` block) or `await` it.

Comment: Hey @CourtneyErickson checking in to see if my last comment makes sense to you.